# 'Of' versus 'for' used in a catch phrase 'love of learning' or 'love for learning'?

Tags: prepositions, of-phrases

Which would be appropriate for use as a catch phrase 'love of learning' or 'love for learning'?  The catch phrase would be included as part of core values in the word L O V E.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=love%20of%20learning%2C%20love%20for%20learning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clove%20of%20learning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clove%20for%20learning%3B%2Cc0), "love of learning" is more widespread compared with "love for learning":

[image]

In the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) there are 66 results for **of** and 4 results for **for**.

Judging by a search in Google Books, both phrases are acceptable, even if the first is used more often.